# how to deal nerual network trainning with big data which needs to be randomly accessed

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, bigdata

My scenario is this. Pick two image from big dataset(which can't be loaded in memory) and compare them with neural network. Each training sample is composed of **randomly** picked two image from the dataset. This random process is required for removing covariance between the cases.

But i can't pick two image from memory. Because computer can't afford the size of the dataset. Therefore each time i makes makes samples, i need to access slow disk. This disk access time slow down learning process a lot. 
So far, My best idea is that randomly divide the dataset to multiple small dataset which is affordable for memory. And then, fully train the neural network with each samll dataset one by one.

But there are possibility that trained model can be distrupted by later small dataset.

So are there good way to dealing this random big data scenario?

Answer (score 0):

What about compressing the images for the training?

After training the network, the classification is usually quite fast. You could try to compress a set of images and buffer them in memory using, for example, a queue which receives a new randomly selected image every n millisecond from a thread. Another thread selects a image from the queue and process it for training. The producer/consumer pattern could be a good choice for such task. 
After training you could do an online compression for the classification task. This will decrease the performance a bit, but because the classification is usually fast, it could be sufficient.